# ckeditor instance inside jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

My problem is when I create ckeditor inside a query dialog, I cannot edit or add text (it doesn't gain focus).

I tried all the solutions in the related questions like creating the instance of the ckeditor when the dialog opens, also I tried to remove all the effects for showing and hiding the dialog... Still the problem occurs. What you think the solution may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing all possibilities, I removed the effects from the dialog and then add a patch js file in the head which was included in jquery bugs in this [link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/attachment/ticket/4727/dialog-patch.js).